# Accessing iOS crash report from iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, crash-reports, crash-dumps

There are quite a few tutorials on how to access crash reports [using a computer](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/debugging/locating-crash-reports.html), but what I would like my app to do is scan for crash reports (from itself) on startup--so that users can use my app to send me their reports. Is this possible?

Comment: maybe you should look at here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041789/comparison-between-testflight-live-quincykit-and-crashlytics
I recommend the crashlytics!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PLCrashReporter](https://www.plcrashreporter.org/) is an open source crash reporting framework that can be added to an iOS App.  Reports are generated in protobuf encoded format, which should allow an app to upload these reports to a server.

Comment: The solutions mentioned by Philippe http://stackoverflow.com/a/10394043/474794 (except testflight) use PLCrashReporter as a foundation and provide all you need to collect those crash reports, symbolicate them and group similar crashes together.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at these few resources that may have the solution you need:

- <del>https://testflightapp.com/</del>
- http://www.hockeyapp.net/
- http://quincykit.net/

Answer (score 2):

You can get them using your itunes connect account

```
 When the user synchronizes their device using iTunes, crash reports are copied to a
directory on the user's computer. If the application was distributed via the App Store and 
the user has chosen to submit crash logs to Apple, the crash log will be uploaded and the 
developer can download it via iTunes Connect.
```

You can also use [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com/) which directly sends you an email once a crash happens.

Comment: iTunes Connect does that in general, but you will not get every single crash, and also not in real time. It sometimes takes weeks until you get anything in there. The problem is the way these reports are send: only if the device owner agreed on device setup time to send usage data and analytics to Apple servers. Most users disagree. And second by the way Apple aggregates them and shows them. Crittercism uses PLCrashReporter as a foundation, just like HockeyApp and QuincyKit and others.

Answer (score 2):

Another proprietary (but free) framework you can use for crash reporting is [Crashlytics](http://crashlytics.com/).