# Objective C code to access device console log in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, console

Is there any way to access the device console log as shown in Xcode -> organiser -> device -> console using objective C.
I have tried using asl.h but it just gives me the nslog messages.What i want is the other messages to read in objective c program which are logged in device console.

Comment: Apple's official public APIs do not allow an iOS app to access Device Logs, assuming you're working an iOS app.

Comment: Check out these previous questions. They provide some possible work arounds for both the console log and the device logs.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394010/accessing-ios-crash-report-from-ios-app
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828965/how-to-read-the-contents-of-the-device-console-on-iphone

Answer (score 1):

In github see this projcet,its help you

https://github.com/sumitmundra/AksDeviceConsole

Comment: i dont want my nslog messages to be read but other console message that are shown in device console xcode organizer

Comment: that's what my comment talking about.